# Unity Project Structure / Cloud Build / Github Action

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, build

Im a currently working on mutliple Unity projects that share quite a lot of prefabs, scripts etc.
More or less those are multiple "minigames" that all have the same foundation.
I am currently showing those Games via WebGL on a Website that requests the data files (wasm, data etc.) from an Azure Blob Storage where I upload the files to.
This upload happens through a separate Page I set up for the various Developers we have in the Team.
The Problem is the following:

- The developers all build the Games on their dev Machines which "locks" the PC from any other use / further development
- They have the "work" of uploading the game via the second webapp

Because of these concerns I wanted to automate this process. My Ideas so far where using Unity Cloud Build (as we already have Unity plus and Teams advanced) or using Github Actions and source controlling it via a Git repository.

My Problems with these 2 options are:

- Cloud build / Collaborate apparently does not support branching (always builds on commit but sometimes those are used for "transferring" progress to another machine), Cloud build is quite difficult to customize to our needs (would have to somehow upload the files after build to the blob storage (supposedly via FTP or something similar)
- I have no experience with source controlling Unity files and Projects with Github (I have knowledge of Github itself and how to use it))

The final Problem I have is that, as said in the beginning, all "Games" are in the same Unity Project in order to make it easier and faster to develop the next games (weekly) and using a source control I do not want to build all games everytime but rather select which one I want to build (cloud build / github action).

So my questions in particular are:

- Is Cloud Build / Github Action feasible for my needs
- How would I control which games to build and deploy and which not (I thought of a triggered build on master/main branch commit and then checking which files have changed and getting the according "game" for those files)
- How much faster / slower would a cloud build solution be compared to a local building option (The devs have quite the machines (i7-10xxx, i9-11xxx + rtx 30xx and m.2 ssds)

Maybe someone with more experience can help me out!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Cloud Build / Github Action feasible for my needs

Yes, Cloud Build is definitely a good option here. You can use Unity's version control ([Plastic SCM](https://unity.com/products/plastic-scm)) to make it easier to work together, you can set [triggers on Plastic SCM](https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/triggers/plastic-scm-version-control-triggers-guide) (after merge/before merge/after code review...etc..) or if you still prefer Github you can still [Github actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows) too. If you want automated builds (Without starting it manually via Unity's dashboard you can set Auto-build option to true in the build config, which will start a cloud build whenever the repository is updated or the branch that you selected to be built.

If you look at the options below you can see that there is much options for automating things.
[image]

> How would I control which games to build and deploy and which not (I thought of a triggered build on master/main branch commit and then checking which files have changed and getting the according "game" for those files)

You can have multiple branches, each branch represents a mini-game. You can trigger a cloud build on specific branch.
For example this is the basic config for a Cloud Build I set up back in time linked with Plastic SCM. You can see the option "Branch" in my case I used a branch named QA but you can use minigame1 or whatever is the name of the game. [image]

> How much faster / slower would a cloud build solution be compared to a local building option (The devs have quite the machines (i7-10xxx, i9-11xxx + rtx 30xx and m.2 ssds)

That can't be decided just like that, it depends how big is your game. You have the option to choose if you want a clean build or normal, obviously a clean build would take more time since it will clear all local files/cache.

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions about how to setup stuff as from what you said  I assumed that you know how to set it up and just asking what is possible.

References:
[Using GitHub with Unity Cloud Build](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/UnityCloudBuildVcsGitHub.html)
[Plastic SCM Cloud build](https://blog.plasticscm.com/2019/03/connect-unity-cloud-build-to-plastic-cloud.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive Answer!
I am going to look more into Cloud Builds and report / ask more specific questions once I am more comfortable with the various Settings and options